# Image in shared layout won't display on one view in area--displays on all others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

My application has a layout that is used in a specific Area. The layout is in `/Views/Shared` and the Area is `/Areas/MyArea`. That layout contains a day/night switcher, and I'm changing the image displayed on the switcher using the following Jquery snippet.

```
function SetMode() {

    if ($('body').hasClass('night-mode')) { // set to day mode
        $('body').removeClass('night-mode').addClass('day-mode');

        $('.mode-picker img').attr('src', '../../Content/Images/night-shift.png');
    } else { // set to night mode
        $('body').removeClass('day-mode').addClass('night-mode');

        $('.mode-picker img').attr('src', '../../Content/Images/day-shift.png');
    }

}
```

On all views but on in the area, this works as expected. One view, however, doesn't show the image and instead shows the following error: `/MyArea/Content/Images/day-shift.png 404 (Not Found)`. In other words, on this one view the layout is looking *in the area* for the content folder and not in the actual content folder.

I've tried copying the images into folders on that path, and then I just get a generic 404 error on the image. There's nothing on the view that is messing with anything in the layout or the mode picker element. I'm honestly not sure what's going on here as this isn't something I've run into before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use relative paths for the img src attribute. Since you are running the script on the same site there is no problem using full URL references.